# For how many values of $x$ are the median and the mean are equal?

Tags: means, gre-exam, median

> [image]

I know how to calculate the mean and the median, but I do not know how to solve this. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: could u give me a hint to start @S.Ong ?

Comment: Consider the three cases: $x < \eta(x), x = \eta(x), x > \eta(x)$. What can you say in each of these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:
Mean = $5+x/5$, and median depends on the value of $x$. Possible arrangements are
$x4579,4x579,45x79,457x9,4579x$.
Calculate the median and check out if the mean can equal the median or not.

Answer (score 2):

The mean of the numbers will be
$$\frac{4+9+7+5+x}{5}=5+\frac{1}{5}x$$

Furthermore, if you put the first four numbers in order from least to greatest,
$$4,5,7,9$$
and then observe all possible placements of $x$ in this ordering:
$$x,4,5,7,9$$
$$4,x,5,7,9$$
$$4,5,x,7,9$$
$$4,5,7,x,9$$
$$4,5,7,9,x$$
You will see that the median cannot be $4$ or $9$, thus it must be $5$, $7$, or $x$. So you can set up and solve the following equations to find the value(s) of $x$:
$$5+\frac{1}{5}x=5$$
$$5+\frac{1}{5}x=7$$
$$5+\frac{1}{5}x=x$$
Can you do that?

Comment: yes I have done it and solved the question thank u so much for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\mu(x)=\frac{4+9+7+5+x}{5}=\frac{25+x}{5}$.

The median must be either $5, x$, or $7$.